# Filtering specific word form sentence by regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regular expression which will give an error when user will give specific input like feat, ft. I do want to allow this kind of input in a sentence. How can I solved this problem.

For example:

The feat-incorrect
featable-corroct

rahin (feat)-incorrect

feat-incorrect

I create one 
 regex: /^(?!.*(feat|artists|Diverse artister|Feat|Feat.Featuring)).*$/

in this regex

featable- is incorrect. But I need this one correct

has  Anyone solved this kind of problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to create a REGEX that selects whole words and not part of a word then try something like this:

```
\bfeat\b
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine. But I need inverse. I don't allow feat

Comment: oh I got it /^(?!.*\bfeat\b).*$/

Answer (score 1):

If you want the only correct word to be featable then use `\bfeatable\b`

check out this [Regex Expression](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) builder, its useful. the builder would highlight the correct words for the expression you put.